# Which primepowers can divide $a^a+b^b$, when gcd(a,b)=1?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Does every primepower $p^n$ divide some number of the form

$$a^a + b^b$$

where a and b are natural numbers and gcd(a,b)=1 ? Without this restriction, the answer
is clearly yes.

If not, what are the conditions for $p^n$ ?

I checked various primepowers and always found a solution,
but I would like to have a general proof.

Comment: My instinct is that you can always find a solution with $b = -1$.

Comment: a and b should be natural. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, there are infinitely many solutions even for $a=1$. You can give an example solution explicitly: $a=1$ and $b=(p-1)p^n-1$ does the job.

The reason is that the modulus of $a^a \bmod m$ only depends on $a \bmod m$ and $a \bmod \varphi(m)$. So $a^a \bmod m$ will be the same if the value of $a \bmod lcm(n,\varphi(n))$ is the same.

In the case of $m = p^n$, we have $M:=lcm(n,\varphi(n)) = (p-1)p^n$. Now $1^1+(-1)^{-1}\equiv 0 \bmod M$, therefore any assignment of $a$ and $b$ such that $a \equiv 1 \bmod M$ and $b \equiv -1 \bmod M$ leads to $a^a + b^b \equiv 0 \bmod p^n$.

Note that this approach is not restricted to prime powers but works for arbitrary numbers instead of $p^n$.